# Solving a finite sum involving spectral methods

Tags: summation

I'm trying to get through Exercise 6.2 of the book Spectral Methods in MATLAB by Nick Trefethen. Exercise 6.1 gives the coefficients of the N+1 by N+1 matrix (indexed from $0$ to $N$) by:
$$D_{ij} = \frac{1}{a_j} \prod^N_{\substack{k=0\\k\neq i,j}}(x_i-x_k) = \frac{a_i}{a_j(x_i-x_j)} \qquad (i\neq j)$$
$$D_{jj} = \sum^N_{\substack{k=0\\k\neq j}}(x_j-x_k)^{-1}$$
where $x_j$ are the Chebyshev points given by
$$x_j = \cos\left(\frac{j\pi}{N}\right) \qquad j = 0,1,\dots,N.$$
I'm trying to derive all the coefficients, but I'm starting with deriving $D_{00}$, which according to the book is given by
$$D_{00} = \frac{2N^2+1}{6}.$$
I checked this for a couple different $N$ and it seems to hold. If we insert $j=0$ to the second formula and substituting the formula for the Chebyshev points for $x_j$ and $x_k$, we get the summation
$$D_{00} = \sum^N_{k=1} \frac{1}{1-\cos(k\pi/N)}.$$
The question is now, where might I go from here? I've tried a lot of things but haven't gotten anywhere. If anyone has any ideas I would very much appreciate it (and maybe some tips for the other coefficients). Thanks!